# Drawing in images

Tags: image-processing, lowpass-filter

I want to develop a procedure to remove some inpainted text from images, i.e. I have to estimate the inpainted pixels. I will do that with first an imputation step and then applying SVD (and perhaps later further improvements).

The imputations step just have to give an initial guess of the inpainted pixels. I thought of applying a gaussian filter to get estimates of the inpainted pixels, but I think this does not give good results.

Does somebody know another way to get good inital guesses, i.e. imputations?

Comment: Are you aware that googleing for "inpainting matlab" will return lots of hits for very sophisticated inpainting algorithms?

Comment: [Here](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~masnou/fichiers/publications/survey.pdf)'s a survey article to get you started.

Comment: I would have a look at blind source separation tutorials and this [dsp question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/implementing-discrete-poisson-equation-wtih-neumann-boundary-condition/1655#1655) for the inpainting.

Answer (score 1):

Proposal 1: Gaussian filter of large radius computed by assigning a null weight to any pixel that belongs to the inpainted area (so that the color of the text you want to get rid of does not "bleed").

Proposal 2: Colour of the nearest pixel which does not belong to the inpainted area.

Proposal 3: For each pixel, randomly sample a handful of points outside of the inpainted area, but not too far away from this pixel. Average the pixel values, weighted by the distance to the pixel.

Comment: Thank you very much.   
Proposal 1: In matlab I have the following code for a gaussian filter:  
`function f=gaussian2d(N,sigma)
 [x y]=meshgrid(round(-N/2):round(N/2), round(-N/2):round(N/2));
 f=exp(-x.^2/(2*sigma^2)-y.^2/(2*sigma^2));
 f=f./sum(f(:));`  
Then I can apply convolution, e.g.  
`filtered_signal=conv2(image,gaussian2d(N,sig),'same');`  
How can I assign null weight to any inpainted pixel? My images are 512x512 pixels and I have a mask of same size for determining where the inpainting is. I.e. the mask is 1 everywhere where an inpainting is and otherwise 0.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to add linebreaks. Proposal 1 continued: With large radius you mean a large N in my above code? I.e. a large kernel matrix.

Comment: @DictionaryProver: " How can I assign null weight to any inpainted pixel?". Simple: You set the inpainted pixel to 0, apply a gaussian filter. Then you apply he same gaussian filter to your mask. Then you divide the two.

Comment: Proposal 2 and 3: How could I do that efficiently? I really don't see it and I think just loops are not good. ;) I think of some matrix operations because I have a mask matrix as said above but I don't see it.

Comment: @nikie: the inpainted pixels are already 0 because they are black. Do I have to do elementwise division, i.e. in Matlab A./B?

Comment: @DictionaryProver: My Matlab knowledge is limited, but elementwise division is what I meant. Basically this says: "My filter result is a fraction between the dot product of the filter kernel any this pixel's neighborhood, divided by the total of the filter kernel"

Comment: @nikie: thank you. The other thing would be matrix division. Do I also have to invert the mask matrix, i.e. setting every 1 (inpaintig) to a 0 (no inpainting) and every 0 to a 1 and then applying the gaussian filter to the mask?

Comment: @DictionaryProver: You lost me there. But it's quite simple: If the non-masked pixels in your source image was 255, then the output should be a uniform (255) image. Which pixels in the mask are 0 and which are 1 should be obvious from that.

Comment: @nikie: alright. By the way, you meant dividing the filtered image by the filtered mask, right? and not dividing the original mask by the filtered mask?

Comment: Is there also a possibility to apply the gaussian filter only to the inpainted pixel + some neighbourhood instead of the whole image? This would save lot of runtime. Does anybody have some suggestion how to implement proposal 2 and 3 from pichenettes in an efficient way? Perhaps using convolution?

Comment: 2 and 3 are non-linear operations, so they cannot be implemented through convolution. I don't have any image processing experience outside C/C++, so I haven't learnt the skill of decomposing algorithms into primitives. nikie's trick for evaluating the weighted convolution is neat!

Comment: Ok, so I will give the gaussian filter a try. I think the trick vom nikie can also be applied to a median filter.

Comment: @nikie: sorry for disturbing you again but I'm still confused with the gaussian filter. Let's say I have an 5x5 pixel image and the pixel in the middle is anomalous and set to 0, every other pixel have value 255. i.e. I want a new value for the pixel in the middle (should be 255). I also have a 5x5 pixel mask with all values zero except the middle value 1 corresponding to the anomalous pixel. Now I would apply the gaussian filter to my original image and then I apply the filter to my mask and divide the filtered image elementwise by the filtered mask. Is this right?

Comment: @nikie: but in the situation I described in my previous comment, I would also have division by zero.

Comment: @nikie: Do you have any suggestions to my last two comments? Vielen Dank and have a nice weekend. ;)

Comment: @DictionaryProver: This was meant to be a "the details are left as an exercise to the reader"-kind of comment ;-). It's really not that hard. Your 5x5 example is quite helpful: You applied your gaussian filter to the 5x5 mask, with all pixels 0.0, except the one in the middle, which is 1.0. Let's say in the filtered mask, the center pixel has the value 0.3. What does that mean? You can interpret it as "the value of this pixel is 0.7 times some mixture of the surrounding pixels, plus 0.3 times the value of the masked out pixel".

Comment: [cont.] So, if you would divide every pixel in your original image by the corresponding pixel in `(1-filter(mask))` (assuming mask was scaled to 0.0 .. 1.0), you would recover exactly the "weighted mixture of the surrounding pixels" from above. Also, for a pixel with no masked pixels in the neighborhood, `(1-filtered(mask))` will be 1, so you divide by 1, i.e. you leave the filtered image alone. As it should be. And, obviously, `(1-filtered(mask))` is the same as `filtered(1-mask)`, for any linear filter

Comment: @nikie: Sorry for my late answer. If I'm dividing my original image by (1-filter(mask)) would this not introduce some division by zero? Moreover, can I also achieve the same result by just applying the filter to the whole original image and then take only the anomalous pixels from the filtered image and the non anomalous pixels from the original image?

Comment: [cont.] A further idea from me is to apply the filter only to the anomalous pixels and some neighborhood of them for saving runtime and then keep the original "good" pixels and replace only the filtered anomalous pixels. But I don't know how I can filter only the anomalous pixels + some neighborhood. Doy ou have an idea how to do that?

Comment: [cont.] I've read that one can select the best filter parameters by using histograms. How can histograms be used for that?

Comment: [cont.] The best parameters for the filter can also be chosen by cross-validation. Currently, I'm tuning the filter by just setting the parameters to different values and then running the filter for 10 images and calculating the mean error and choosing the parameters with lowest error. But this is not cross-validation. In cross-validation I would had to split the 10 images to a training and test set and first train the parameters on the training set and then using the test set for testing it. But how can I use the training set for training the parameters?

Comment: @nikie: Do you have any suggestions to my last two comments? Vielen Dank and have a nice day. :)

Comment: @DictionaryProver In the spirit of "teaching a man how to fish and he will never be hungry again": You should be able to answer all those questions yourself. It's just basic algebra. To make it simple, imagine you had 1d data `a,b,c,[missing],e,f,g`, a mask `1,1,1,0,1,1,1`, and a filter kernel `1/4,2/4,1/4`. If you convolve the data with the filter, what do you get? (Write it down!) If you convolve the mask with the filter,what do you get? What result would you expect? How can you get that (using division)? Under what circumstances would you get division by zero? What would you expect instead?

Comment: @nikie: I tried out your example. I'm assuming that the missing pixel has value 0, i.e. we have a,b,c,0,e,f,g. I'm now only looking at convolving the missing center pixel. For the data we get for the center pixel 1/4c + 1/4e and for the mask we get 2/4. If we divide the convolved center pixel by the convolved mask we get (1/4c + 1/4e) / (2/4) = 0.5c + 0.5e. But why do we want 0.5c + 0.5e and not just 1/4c + 1/4e?

Comment: [cont.] Division by zero can occur if there are in the mask 3 zeros in a row, e.g. 1,1,0,0,0,1,1. If we convole the center we get 0. This would lead to division by zero for the center. That means that I have to add e.g. eps if division by zero can occur, right?

Comment: 1. "But why do we want 0.5c + 0.5e and not just 1/4c + 1/4e" - if the inpainted pixels are a weighted sum of the surrounding pixels, we would want the weights to add up to 1, right? Otherwise, the inpainted areas would be darker than the surrounding area

Comment: 2. Exactly, division by zero happens when you have no basically no information about the inpainted pixel, because all the "good pixels" are too far away. You have to decide what result you want in that case: Do you want black pixels? Then add eps to the denominator. White pixels? Then add eps to numerator and denominator. Or you could use a larger mask for those pixels. Or maybe leave them masked and run the inpainting algorithm again on the result image (and repeat until all pixels are filled). You could probably come up with more ideas - it really depends on your application which one's best

Comment: @nikie: you give me some good hints. I think about calculating connected regions for "bad pixels" and then adapt the kernel size to the width of every region. But how should I caluclate the width? Should I just fit a rectangle around each group of connected bad pixels and take the width of the rectangle? But this could be bad for certain shapes, e.g. for a horizontal bar, the width would be equal to the width of the bar and this would lead to a too large kernel.